# Apple TV crashes internet upon startup for 5 minutes

Tags: wifi, appletv

We just got the Apple TV 4K and are having a weird problem. When Apple TV is plugged in and setup and we turn on our TV (Samsung), our internet completely crashes. After about 4-5 minutes everything reconnects and once it reconnects, everything that was connected to wifi works perfectly (including the Apple TV).

I thought it was the Apple TV but we bought another one and are having the same issue. What's weird is that we used to have a Roku stick and didn't have any issues - it's only with the Apple TV. Internet also only drops when we turn on the TV (which boots up Apple TV) but not during any other time.

I have the Apple TV right next to my Verizon Fios router and again, haven't had any issues prior to using Apple TV. I've tried looking at my router settings and have upgraded firmware but can't figure it out.

Has anyone else ever had this problem?
Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Are you connecting the ATV via ethernet or wifi?  What happens when you using the other method to connect?

Comment: Both results are the same. Kicks me off everything as soon as I turn on the TV

Comment: Is the Apple TV software up to date?

Comment: Yup latest software too

Comment: Have you rebooted your Verizon router? Is the Samsung also connected to the internet as well as the Apple TV?

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes I've rebooted my router a few times. Samsung is also connected to the internet which works fine as well. Never had any issues with connection crashing

Comment: I can only guess that the IP addresses being handed out via DHCP to the Samsung are getting munged up somehow. Here's an odd request, but worth trying - power down all other devices using WiFi (phones, iPads, computers, etc) and see if the problem occurs.

Comment: @icondaemon - That worked! I unplugged my Samsung from the internet and Apple TV works no problem.  I'll just keep it unplugged because I don't use it for anything and now have Apple TV to do the work. Thanks so much for the help! It was driving me crazy and I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is some IP address conflict created by your router and the devices on the network.

If you are not using the WiFi/ethernet connection on the Samsung, disable WiFi or unplug the ethernet cable to remote it from your network.